# AWS Textract StartDocumentAnalysis function not publishing a message to the SNS Topic

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, aws-sdk, aws-sdk-nodejs, amazon-textract

I am working with AWS Textract and I want to analyze a multipage document, therefore I have to use the async options, so I first used `startDocumentAnalysis`function and I got a JobId as the return, But it needs to trigger a function that I have set to trigger when the SNS topic got a message.

These are my serverless file and handler file.

```
provider:
  name: aws
  runtime: nodejs8.10
  stage: dev
  region: us-east-1
  iamRoleStatements:
    - Effect: "Allow"
      Action:
       - "s3:*"
      Resource: { "Fn::Join": ["", ["arn:aws:s3:::${self:custom.secrets.IMAGE_BUCKET_NAME}", "/*" ] ] }
    - Effect: "Allow"
      Action:
        - "sts:AssumeRole"
        - "SNS:Publish"
        - "lambda:InvokeFunction"
        - "textract:DetectDocumentText"
        - "textract:AnalyzeDocument"
        - "textract:StartDocumentAnalysis"
        - "textract:GetDocumentAnalysis"
      Resource: "*"

custom:
  secrets: ${file(secrets.${opt:stage, self:provider.stage}.yml)}

functions:
  routes:
    handler: src/functions/routes/handler.run
    events:
      - s3:
          bucket: ${self:custom.secrets.IMAGE_BUCKET_NAME}
          event: s3:ObjectCreated:*

  textract:
    handler: src/functions/routes/handler.detectTextAnalysis
    events:
      - sns: "TextractTopic"

resources:
  Resources:
    TextractTopic:
        Type: AWS::SNS::Topic
        Properties:
          DisplayName: "Start Textract API Response"
          TopicName: TextractResponseTopic
```

Handler.js

```
module.exports.run = async (event) => {
  const uploadedBucket = event.Records[0].s3.bucket.name;
  const uploadedObjetct = event.Records[0].s3.object.key;

  var params = {
    DocumentLocation: {
      S3Object: {
        Bucket: uploadedBucket,
        Name: uploadedObjetct
      }
    },
    FeatureTypes: [
      "TABLES", 
      "FORMS"
    ],
    NotificationChannel: {
      RoleArn: 'arn:aws:iam::<accont-id>:role/qvalia-ocr-solution-dev-us-east-1-lambdaRole', 
      SNSTopicArn: 'arn:aws:sns:us-east-1:<accont-id>:TextractTopic'
    }
  };

  let textractOutput = await new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    textract.startDocumentAnalysis(params, function(err, data) {
      if (err) reject(err); 
      else resolve(data);
    });
  });
}
```

I manually published an sns message to the topic and then it is firing the textract lambda, which currently has this,

```
module.exports.detectTextAnalysis = async (event) => {
  console.log('SNS Topic isssss Generated');
  console.log(event.Records[0].Sns.Message);
};
```

What is the mistake that I have and why the textract startDocumentAnalysis is not publishing a message and making it trigger the lambda?

Note: I haven't use the startDocumentTextDetection before using the startTextAnalysis function, though it is not necessary to call it before this.

Comment: Does `qvalia-ocr-solution-dev-us-east-1-lambdaRole` have enough permissions to publish over SNS?

Comment: I am also working in amazon textract and the SNS publishing was working about a week ago and now it isn't. I have an application that I didn't change anything in the publishing and now it is broken. The dev must have broken it since it is open preview still.

Comment: @griff4594 I have the same problem and I'm like crazy trying to figure it out what is wrong with this. Thanks for your comment

Comment: @griff4594 I noticed that if a use a permit all policy in the role that push to SNS it works. I don't know what permission I'm forgetting to make it work

Comment: @RubenJGarcia I got mine working because of the IAM role I'm using was not allowing Textract specifically in the Trusted Relationships.
```{
  "Version": "2012-10-17",
  "Statement": [
    {
      "Effect": "Allow",
      "Principal": {
        "Service": [
          "lambda.amazonaws.com",
          "textract.amazonaws.com"
        ]
      },
      "Action": "sts:AssumeRole"
    }
  ]
}```

Answer (score 10):

Make sure you have in your Trusted Relationships of the role you are using:

```
{
  "Version": "2012-10-17",
  "Statement": [
    {
      "Effect": "Allow",
      "Principal": {
        "Service": [
          "lambda.amazonaws.com",
          "textract.amazonaws.com"
        ]
      },
      "Action": "sts:AssumeRole"
    }
  ]
}
```

Comment: This answer and in combination with ensuring that I have both the "sts:AssumeRole" and "sns:Publish" permissions is what worked for me. Thanks!

Answer (score 5):

The SNS Topic name must be AmazonTextract

At the end your arn should look this:

```
arn:aws:sns:us-east-2:111111111111:AmazonTextract
```

Comment: Yes, if you use the aws-managed policy "AmazonTextractServiceRole", it is resource-restricted to "arn:aws:sns:*:*:AmazonTextract*", meaning that your SNS topic name must at least *start with* "AmazonTextract"

Answer (score 0):

If you have your bucket encrypted you should grant kms permissions, otherwise it won't work

Comment: can you please specify which KMS actions are you referring to?

Answer (score 0):

I was able got this working directly via Serverless Framework by adding a Lambda execution resource to my `serverless.yml` file:

```
resources:
  Resources:
    IamRoleLambdaExecution:
      Type: AWS::IAM::Role
      Properties:
        AssumeRolePolicyDocument:
          Version: "2012-10-17"
          Statement:
            - Effect: Allow
              Principal:
                Service:
                  - lambda.amazonaws.com
                  - textract.amazonaws.com
              Action: sts:AssumeRole
```

And then I just used the same role generated by Serverless (for the lambda function) as the notification channel role parameter when starting the Textract document analysis:

Thanks to this [this post](https://gist.github.com/sdomagala/a647a69f0dd87af545d7c45dfc7b0114) for pointing me in the right direction!

Answer (score 0):

For anyone using the CDK in TypeScript, you will need to add Lambda as a ServicePrincipal as usual to the Lambda Execution Role. Next, access the `assumeRolePolicy` of the execution role and call the `addStatements` method.

**The basic execution role without any additional statement (add those later)**

```
  this.executionRole = new iam.Role(this, 'ExecutionRole', {
    assumedBy: new ServicePrincipal('lambda.amazonaws.com'),
  });
```

**Next, add Textract as an additional ServicePrincipal**

```
  this.executionRole.assumeRolePolicy?.addStatements(
    new PolicyStatement({
      principals: [
        new ServicePrincipal('textract.amazonaws.com'),
      ],
      actions: ['sts:AssumeRole']
    })
  );
```

**Also, ensure the execution role has full permissions on the target SNS topic (note the topic is created already and accessed via fromTopicArn method)**

```
 const stmtSNSOps = new PolicyStatement({
    effect: iam.Effect.ALLOW,
    actions: [
      "SNS:*"
    ],
    resources: [
      this.textractJobStatusTopic.topicArn
    ]
  });
```

**Add the policy statement to a global policy (within the active stack)**

```
 this.standardPolicy = new iam.Policy(this, 'Policy', {
    statements: [
      ...
      stmtSNSOps, 
      ...
    ]
  });
```

**Finally, attach the policy to the execution role**

```
  this.executionRole.attachInlinePolicy(this.standardPolicy);
```